# JAX-RS Accept header param compatibality

Tags: java, jax-rs, http-accept-language

If the `Accept` header param string has multiple media types that are acceptable such as:

```
text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
```

How to find if the media type is compatible with a single MediaType object?

If the `Accept` header contains a single media type then it works.

```
MediaType.valueOf(acceptHeaderparam).isCompatible(MediaType.valueOf(contentType)
```

Is there some method such as `MediaType.isCompatible(String)`?

**NOTE:** `@Consumes` header can not be used because the custom media types are supported and the all the media types can not be determined at the compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public boolean isCompatible(String mediaTypeStr, String contentType) {
    MediaType type = MediaType.valueOf(contentType);
    return Arrays.stream(mediaTypeStr.split(","))
                 .map(t -> MediaType.valueOf(t.trim()))
                 .anyMatch(type::isCompatible);
}
```